# DateTime.ParseExact format exception

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I'm new to VB.net so please bear with me a bit.

I'm trying to parse date/time data out of a data file:

```
Dim line As String = "    Stime 31/05/2016 08:29:36"
Dim start_time As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(line, "    Stime dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

System.FormatException was unhandled Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
Line:   "    Stime 31/05/2016 08:29:36"
format: "    Stime dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```

There is white space allover the string to be parsed, and an ignorable string of characters 'Stime' in the string to be parsed. I did look at other examples of this and questions people have asked which got me this far, but none of them had a string of characters in them that could be ignored or white space, I'm not entirely sure how that affects what I'm trying to do.

Thank you guys, I appreciate you taking a moment to help me out.

Comment: You could also use Trim to get rid of the whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *Stime* contains characters used in the [Custom DateTime format string patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) `t` and `m`, you need to escape them

```
Dim start_time As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(line, "    S\ti\me dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```